# How to remove the word "Navigation" from the top of the mobile main menu?

Tags: navigation, mobile

How can I remove the word "navigation" from the top of `www.kpvitamins.com`? I also would like to remove the entire navigation because as you can see at the top, I have a different one.

Comment: There's a lot missing form this question, such as the code that displays the navigation, what theme you're using, etc etc

Answer (score 0):

Add following CSS code in `style.css` file of your theme.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px){
.menu-toggle { display: none; }
}
```